# grep in perl without array

Tags: perl, grep

If I have one variable : I assigned entire file text to it

```
$var = `cat file_name`
```

Suppose in the file , the word 'mine' comes in 17th line (location is not available but just giving example) and I want to search a pattern 'word' after N (eg 10) lines of word 'mine' if pattern 'word' exist in those lines or not. How can i do that in the regular expression without using array'

Example:

```
$var = "I am good in perl\n but would like to know about the \n grep command in details";
```

I want to search particular pattern in specific lines (lines 2 to 3 only). How can I do it without using array.

Comment: You cannot do it without using an array. You'll have to split your string into an array of lines first.

Comment: I'm sure this can be done without using an array if you're willing to forgo `grep`, but it will be ugly... who do you want this?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is a valid case for not using arrays here - when files are prohibitively large.

This is a pretty specific requirement. Rather than beat around the bush to find that Perl idiom, I'd prescribe a subroutine:

```
 sub n_lines_apart {

    my ( $file, $n, $first_pattern, $second_pattern ) = @_;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    my $lines_apart;

    while (<$fh>) {

        $lines_apart++ if qr/$first_pattern/ .. qr/$second_pattern/;
    }

    return $lines_apart && $lines_apart <= $n+1;
}
```

**Caveat**

The sub above is not designed to handle multiple matches in a single file. Let that be an exercise for the reader.

Comment: OP states that the entire file contents are in a single variable, so he's already slurped it into a scalar, which means the file is not prohibitively large. But +1 anyhow because reading the file one line at a time instead of slurping it is generally The Right Thing To Do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression match like this:

```
my $var = `cat $filename`;
while ( $var =~ /foo/g ) {
    print $1, "\n";
    print "match occurred at position ", pos($var), " in the string.\n";
}
```

This will print out all the matches of the string 'foo' from your string, similar to grep but not using an array (or list). The /$regexp/g syntax makes the regular expression iteratively match against the string from left to right.

I'd recommend reading [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) for a tutorial on matching with regular expressions.

Comment: i want to find the pattern only in 10 lines after another specific pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
perl -ne '$m=$. if !$m && /first-pattern/;
print if $m && ($.-$m >= 2 && $.-$m <= 3) && /second-pattern/'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Updated. I swear it did answer it for me when I read the question first time. They must have edited it